# ¿Cómo hacer focus automáticamente con jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Quisiera saber cómo podría hacer focus a los elementos DOM de mi página web progresivamente, es decir que haga focus es un `<a>` (por ejemplo) y después de 5 segundos, hacer focus al siguiente; y así seguir con todos los elementos.

Inicialmente tenía este código (visto en internet):

```
function recorrido(){
    $("#menu a").each(function(){
        $(this).focus();
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(e){
    recorrido();
});
```

Pero ese código no me funcionaba, así que opté por darles distintas clases, pero si lo dejo con el tiempo (como se verá abajo), entonces no me cambia las clases y nada se modifica.

```js
<section id="menu">
  <a href="" id="refrescar_inicio">Inicio</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <a href="#estadisticas" id="mostrar_estadisticas">Estad&iacute;sticas</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <a href="#modelo" id="mostrar_modelo">Modelo</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <a href="#conceptos" id="mostrar_conceptos">Conceptos</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="" id="mostrar_como">C&oacute;mo usar</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <a href="" id="mostrar_blog">Ir al blog</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <a href="./php/registrar.html" id="enviar_registrar">Registrarse</a>
</section>
```

```css
#menu{
 background-color:#F5F5F5;
 padding:1em;
 text-align:center;
}
#menu a{
 color:#000000;
 font-size:20pt;
}
.focus{
 outline: thick double #32a1ce;
}
```

```html
function recorrido(){
 $("#menu a").each(function(){
  $(this).addClass('focus');
  }).then(function(){
   $(this).removeClass('focus')
 });
}

$(document).ready(function(e){
 recorrido();
});
```

Quisiera saber cómo podría hacer focus a todos los elementos, independiente de su etiqueta, o cómo podría agregarle una clase especial y luego de 5 segundos, quitar esa clase y ponérsela al elemento siguiente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente lo que necesitas hacer primero que todo es utilizar un `setInterval` para ejecutar tu código cada 5 segundos así como lo pides.

Le asignamos al primer `<a>` por defecto la clase `focus` para usar esta clase como selector, seleccionamos el elemento siguiente utilizando el método `.next()`, luego de esto seleccionamos el elemento anterior al último elemento con clase `focus` utilizando el método `.prev()`  y le removemos la clase.

Espero haber sido claro en la explicación, acá te dejo tu ejemplo funcional:

```js
function recorrido(){
  $("#menu a.focus").next().addClass('focus');
  $("#menu a.focus").prev().removeClass('focus');
}

$(document).ready(function(e){
  setInterval(function(){
    recorrido();
  }, 5000)
});
```

```css
#menu{
 background-color:#F5F5F5;
 padding:1em;
 text-align:center;
}
#menu a{
 color:#000000;
 font-size:20pt;
}
.focus{
 outline: thick double #32a1ce;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="menu">
  <a href="" id="refrescar_inicio" class="focus">Inicio</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <a href="#estadisticas" id="mostrar_estadisticas">Estad&iacute;sticas</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <a href="#modelo" id="mostrar_modelo">Modelo</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <a href="#conceptos" id="mostrar_conceptos">Conceptos</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="" id="mostrar_como">C&oacute;mo usar</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <a href="" id="mostrar_blog">Ir al blog</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <a href="./php/registrar.html" id="enviar_registrar">Registrarse</a>
</section>
```

Comment: Perfecto. Muchísimas gracias, amigo. Ya califiqué tu pregunta.

Comment: Oye, una pregunta: ¿Cómo podría ser, con ese código, pero para todos los elementos de una página?

Comment: @SantiagoCorreaAguirreSanmar debes cambiar los dos selectores `$("#menu a.focus")` por el selector `$("* .focus")`